# linux + limits.conf configuration

Tags: linux, rhel, ulimit

I asked to configure the following ulimit parameters with the following values for the user oracle

expect results

```
$ ulimit -Su
2047
$ ulimit -Hu
16384
```

what need to set in the **/etc/security/limits.conf** file

in order to get the 2047 from `ulimit -Su`
and 16384 from the `ulimit -Hu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents max num of process. Just add below mentioned lines in limits.conf.

```
oracle soft nproc 2047

oracle hard nproc 16384
```